# How to make a node in D3 Three dimensional

Tags: javascript, 3d, d3.js

I have a d3 application where i am using 5 nodes to show some relationship.I want to make the nodes 3 dimensional in this application.can anyone help me?

Example data, with regular 2D force-directed layout implemented:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/vuCAx/

please anyone help me to do this..

Comment: What do you want to show by making them 3D? D3 doesn't support 3D directly, you'll have to use a third-party library for that.

Comment: can you help me by suggesting the name of that library?

Comment: [Here](http://makc3d.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/using-d3-js-with-three-js/) is an article with three.js.

Comment: There have been some efforts to adapt d3 to 3d.  [Discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/d3-js/3d/d3-js/N7ewY3F2sTs/sYGQcHRwu-wJ)  The last post describes [this visualization](https://vida.io/documents/N4jSip7n68yQ48DXp) which looks like what you want; you could contact the creator for tips or permission to use his code.

Comment: @AmeliaBR how can i contact the creator?can you please help me?